# Is there any option to stop applying analyzer?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am developing mini application using Elastic Search.

Setting :-

```
        settingBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                .startObject("index")
                .startObject("analysis")
                .startObject("analyzer")
                .startObject("custom_analyzer")
                .field("type", "custom")
                .field("tokenizer","keyword")
                .field("filter", new String[]{"standard","ngram_filters"})
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .startObject("filter")
                .startObject("ngram_filters")
                .field("type", "nGram")
                .field("min_gram", "1")
                .field("max_gram","10")
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .endObject();
```

Mapping :-

```
        contentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
        .startObject("students")
        .startObject("properties")
        .startObject("searchColumn")
        .field("analyzer", "custom_analyzer")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        .startObject("firstName")
        .field("type","string")
        .field("analyzer", "custom_analyzer")
        .field("store", "yes")
        .endObject()
        .startObject("lastName")
        .field("type","string")
        .field("analyzer", "custom_analyzer")
        .field("store", "yes")
        .endObject()
        .startObject("registerNumber")
        .field("type", "long")
        .field("analyzer", "custom_analyzer")
        .field("store", "yes")
        .endObject()
        .endObject()
        .endObject()
        .endObject();
```

Here i specified nGram filter. but for some reason while doing search process i dont want to apply analyzer for prefixFilter or prefixQuery. is there any option.
The issue i am facing here is,

for eg.

```
    apple
    one apple
    two apple
```

assume that those are firstName values from example.
  when i search prefix a character 'a', i must want to get only 'apple' document. but right now, i am getting all the results because of nGram... can u please any solution for this?

Comment: Could you shed some light on whether the answer was useful or completely off? :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define the mapping for your [string fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/) you can define different analyzers applied at index time and query time, just using the `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer` property. You're currently using the `analyzer` property which is a shortcut to apply the same analyzer at both index and query time. In fact you usually have a similar, if not equal, text analysis chain applied at index time and query time, but ngrams are definitely an exception since you don't want to make ngrams out of your queries.

You just to define two different analyzers, one that makes ngrams and the other that doesn't. Update then your mapping like this:

```
.startObject("firstName")
.field("type","string")
.field("index_analyzer", "ngrams_analyzer")
.field("search_analyzer", "search_analyzer_without_ngrams")
```

Comment: Will this fix his problem though? He (or she) said a search for "a" should only match "apple" and not "one apple". But if "one apple" is ngramed at index time then it will match (if the `min_gram` is 1).

Comment: @ramseykhalaf I think so. That part of the question is not that clear but if I got it right the problem is just about stop making ngrams at query time. Anyways, I guess we'll find out soon! :)